# if cell in column A is blank then vlookup column B against dataset in different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a simple macro that will identify any blank cells in column A and then automatically run a vlookup using column B against a dataset I have created in another sheet.

I'm trying to run a reconciliation between 2 books and records.  However, the unique identifiers in the 2 files either match or the cell is blank so I created a new table using "description" to populate a unique identifier that would help match the 2 records.

``````````
Records A
`````````
Unique Identifier   |   Description     |   Units
--------------------+-------------------+---------
ADFVBC              |   Alpha Ventures  |   1234
<blank>             |   KDN holdings    |   2155
DQDW1               |   Capital ORD     |   3214

Records B
`````````
Unique Identifier   |   Description         |   Units
--------------------+-----------------------+---------
ADFVBC              |   Alpha Ventures      |   1234
<blank>             |   **KDN holdings INC  |   2155
DQDW1               |   Capital ORD         |   3214
``````````

Created Identifiers

```
Records A description   |   Records B description   |   Created Identifiers
------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------------
KDN Holdings            |   **KDN Holdings Inc      |   IDENTIFIER1
```

For example, both files have KDN Holdings but the unique identifier in both RecordsA & RecordsB is blank.  Furthermore, both descriptions are different.  I created a new sheet to create an identifier using the 2 different descriptions.  In yellow I highlighted the equation I hope to have a macro autopopulate whenever the macro recognizes column A is blank.

I want to enter into the blank cell a formula that vlookup the description against my created unique identifier dataset

```
=VLOOKUP(B10,Identifiers!A:C,3,FALSE)
```

Not sure if this is possible.. would love to hear feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I also included lots of comments to better explain what the code is doing...

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer ' first create variables you might need (I always include a few integers)
Dim aRec As Worksheet, bRec As Worksheet, ident As Worksheet, wb As Workbook ' first create variables you might need

Dim aDesc As String, bDesc As String ' first create variables you might need

Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook ' This assumes your currently active workbook is the one we need to use.
Set aRec = wb.Sheets("Records A") ' Assuming your worksheet names are "Records A", "Records B", and "Identifiers"
Set bRec = wb.Sheets("Records B") ' Assuming your worksheet names are "Records A", "Records B", and "Identifiers"
Set ident = wb.Sheets("Identifiers") ' Assuming your worksheet names are "Records A", "Records B", and "Identifiers"

With aRec ' Using the "Records A" worksheet . . .
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Loop through each row in the used range...
        If Trim(.Cells(i, 1).Value) = "" Then ' Check if the cell value is blank. I added the "trim" function to eliminate leading or trailing spaces.
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = "=VLOOKUP(" & .Cells(i, 2).Address(0, 0, xlA1) & ", Identifiers!A:C,3,FALSE)"
        End If
    Next i
End With

With bRec ' Using the "Records B" worksheet . . .
    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Loop through each row in the used range...
        If Trim(.Cells(i, 1).Value) = "" Then ' Check if the cell value is blank. I added the "trim" function to eliminate leading or trailing spaces.
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = "=VLOOKUP(" & .Cells(i, 2).Address(0, 0, xlA1) & ", Identifiers!B:C,2,FALSE)" ' <-- notice how I offset this one a little to account for the new description location on the identifiers sheet
        End If
    Next i
End With



End Sub
```

Comment: @xslyx You're welcome, sir! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct (and maybe an up-vote if you enjoyed the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The `If` condition is missing a closing bracket:
    `If IsEmpty(Cells(i,1)) Then`
The `IsEmpty()` function has one set of brackets and 
the `Cells()` function has one set of brackets
`Cells()` is embedded in `IsEmpty()`

Comment: Thanks JMMach.  How would I adjust this syntax if I want the code to search column A for blank cell.  I'm trying to figure this out myself but not making much progress.

Answer (score 0):

Will be something like this:

```
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i,1) Then 'if cell in A is empty
        Cells(i,1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[+1]Identifiers!C1:C3,3,FALSE) 'Lookup cell in B in Identifier A:C
    End If
Next
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), Lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
MsgBox LastRow
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then 'if cell in A is empty
        Cells(i, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[1],Identifiers!C1:C3,3,FALSE)" 'Lookup cell in B in Identifier A:C
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Works like a charm for my test dataset.

Comment: I'm getting a compile error on the Then part.  Not sure how to troubleshoot

Comment: When i replaced the vlookup formula with another equation =INDEX(Sheet1!E:E,MATCH(PMR!B:B,Sheet1!A:A,0)), my formula comes out with extra characters for some reason.  Any ideas?  It shows up as =INDEX(Sheet1!E:(E),MATCH(PMR!B:(B),Sheet1!A:(A),0))